# Clean solution for multiple loop and conditional

Tags: objective-c, refactoring, dry

Lets say I've got following case:

```
NSError *error;
for (NSObject1 *obj1 in objects1) {
    [sth doSomethingWithObj1:obj1 withError:&error];
}
for (NSObject2 *obj in objects2) {
    [sth doSomethingWithObj2:obj2 withError:&error];
}
for (NSObject3 *obj in objects3) {
    [sth doSomethingWithObj3:obj3 withError:&error];
}
for (NSObject4 *obj in objects4) {
    [sth doSomethingWithObj4:obj4 withError:&error];
}
[sth doSomethingWithObj5:obj5 withError:&error];
```

The objects are obviously different, the methods are different too. I'd like to print the error if it appeared. I want to keep the code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), so repeating this is a wrong solution:

```
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error occurred: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    return; // can be but doesn't have to
}
```

I wouldn't like to have to refactor these `doSomethingWithObjX:` methods, as they're used in many other places (so using blocks instead of errors isn't a great idea).

I thought of using [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org), but the project is valid for iOS 7 (PromiseKit 3.0 is not compatible, last one was 1.6), and also it would require massive amount of work to refactor underlying classes, so I've resigned this idea.

How can I write it this way, that the code is pretty & DRY while the check is done after each place the modification happens?

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: @DuncanC You're fast with voting to close. Added the question.

Comment: Actually that wasn't me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to only perform each loop if error is still `nil`, and add the `if(error)` block at the end.

BTW: Sometimes making it DRY makes it also less readable, especially in an easy case is this.

Comment: It won't be less readable, there's quite a lot of these loops. Instead of focusing on the context only the error handling will be visible. Your option is good if I'd like to add that `return` statement (+1 from me ;)). What if not..?

Comment: If not you could collect the errors in an array, and still print them at the end, looping over the array.